# Can't set --exclude-path for jshint in folder

Tags: javascript, jshint

so my jshint is working fine with the .jshintignore in the root.

But I want it in a folder and named foo.

so I have this

```
/root
    /bar
       foo
.jshintrc
```

I am trying to run the code with

```
jshint . --exclude-path bar/foo
```

If I have foo at the root and do

```
jshint . --exclude-path foo
```

it works.

Can anyone tell me how to have my .jshintignore in a directory other than root?

I also see that you can use the --exclude tag but it won't specify more than one directory either.

Comment: Docs are here but I don't see anything on formatting the flag http://jshint.com/docs/cli/#flags

Answer (score 0):

This is how I overcame the problem but its not the solution I wanted.

I decided to use command line args to achieve the same effect.

```
find . -type f -name "*.js" | grep -v node_modules | grep -v "js/" | grep -v "test" | xargs jshint --config=node_modules/bdsft-sdk-core/.jshintrc
```